# Replace multiple lines with a single

Tags: unix, sed

I have a file which contains a lot of certificates along with other texts as shown below.

```
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
asdqwejljlajlsjdlajdhlakshfaksf
ajsdlahlasd;ajdpjadsadaljdslasd
asdhashdkashdladlajdlakjsdakjdla
alksdjladlajdajd;ad;asldadalsdka
-----END CERTIFICATE------
asasd asdasd asdasd
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
asdasdalsdasdasdadsasda
asdasdadsasdadsasd
asdadadsadasd
asdasdadsadadasdasd
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I want to replace the certificate from -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE to END CERTIFICATE----- with  in the file globally.

It should look like this :

```
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
<removed-cert>
asasd asdasd asdasd
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
<removed-cert>
```

I used the below command but I get the error

```
sed 's(/BEGIN/,/END/)/<removed-cert>/g' file_name
Error :: sed: -e expression #1, char 28: unterminated `s' command
```

Can someone please help ?

Comment: What research did you do?

Answer (score 0):

`sed` primarily doesn't work with newlines, better tool to work with multiple line selections is `awk`:

```
awk '/-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----/ {f=1}
f==1 {}
f==0 {print}
/-----END CERTIFICATE-----/ {f=0 ; print "<removed-cert>"}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the file directly, you can use `ed`:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'g/^--*BEGIN/.,/^--*END/c\' '<removed-cert>' w | ed -s input.txt 
$ cat input.txt
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
<removed-cert>
asasd asdasd asdasd
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
<removed-cert>
```

Translated: For every line starting with one or more dashes and the word BEGIN, **c**hange the region from that line to the next one starting with one or more dashes and the word END to `<removed-cert>`, and finally **w**rite the changed file back out.